# Gsub to keep string between ;

Tags: text-processing, r

I have a a dataset in R:

"Pppppp;Cccccccc;Ooooo;My_string;Gggggg;"

I would like to keep Mystring (so to remove everything before and after). My string is always located after the third ";". The length of Pppppp, Ccccc, Oooo and Ggggg is not the same form one line to another.

Any idea how to do this?

I tried to generated patterns :

```
gsub(pattern="\\w[;]{3}", replacement="")
```

but I always ended up with removing of " ; " but not the strings...

This is not a tab separated file

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your string always after the 3rd ";" starting from your left to right? Also what do you mean for "it is not a tab separated file?" You can import it as a table in R using as separator ";" something like:

`tmp <- read.table("your.file.txt", sep=";", header=F)`

then you select the 4th column (that is the one after the 3rd ";"):
`my_strings <- tmp$V4`

This is using R.

Comment: This was really helpful and I realized that my file was a mess, a mix of ";" and "\t". Thanks!

Comment: @Nathalie you can sign as answered the questions now. Happy this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I think you can achieve your goal doing this:

```
 awk -F ";" '{OFS=";";print $1,$2,$3,$4}' input_file
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, I edit my question to make it clearer. This is not a file with tab, so I can't use awk and print. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry @Nathalie, I didn't know the existence of a "R Language".. Now I do ;-)
Thanks to you.

Comment: @Daniel for her purpose would be perfect with awk in this way:          `awk -F ";" '{print $4}' my.file > output.file` because she needs the 4th column..

Comment: Hi @fusion.slope. For sure. At the time of my answer, I didn't realize what she really needs... Thank you.